# Syntax error python, not sure how to write the code

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that tests a word to see if it is a palindrome or not. It is working but it prints NO in a loop before it gives the correct answer. I want it to just print the correct answer once.

I haven't really done anything, just checked the internet for some answers

```
x = str(input("enter the word:"))

w = "" 

for i in x: 
    w = i + w 
    if x == w: 
        print("YES") 
    else:
        print("NO")
```

It should print YES or NO once, now it prints many times before giving the correct answer.

Comment: Fix your indentation, please.

Answer (score 2):

indent the w= i + w line

```
x = str(input("enter the word:"))

w = "" 

for i in x: 

  w = i + w 

if (x==w): 
    print("YES") 
else:
    print("NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your indentation to make it possible to trouble shoot.

At first glance it appears your “if” statement is nested in side your “for” loop, thus checking for the palindrome after each letter is added.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the if else inside the loop, its bound to print the result multiple times. Keep it out of the loop and it will print just once.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Community!

A shorter way to do this could be:`

```
x = str(input("enter the word:"))
if (x==x[::-1]): 
    print("YES") 
else:
    print("NO")
```

You may want to look into string slicing in python :)

Answer (score 0):

Mark B already solved your issue but here is an additional method out of interest.

```
word = input("Enter word")

reverse = word[::-1]

if word == reverse:
    print("Yes, plaindrome")
else:
    print("No, not palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your for loop to create a new string ( reverse of string x ). Use conditional outside the for loop. Also, check for uppercase entry.